# How to parse a URL query string and create a user-specified struct from that?

Tags: rust

Adding more detail to my [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806184/how-to-create-a-struct-from-key-value-pairs) question, I need a function that will parse a URL query string and create a struct based on a struct type, like:

```rust
struct Obj {
    key: String,
    key2: Vec<String>,
};

let obj: Obj = parse("...example.com/path?key=value&key1=value1&key2=value2")?;
// should return > Obj { key: "value", key2: ["value1","value2"] }

let _obj: Obj = parse("...example.com/path?key2=value1&key2=value2")?;
// should return error because `key` isn't present,

struct NewObj {
    key: String,
    key2: u8,
    key3: bool,
}

let new_obj: NewObj = parse("...example.com/path?key=value&key1=255&key3=true")?;
// should return > NewObj { key: "value", key2: 255, key3: true  }
```

Comment: Write a trait that both `Obj` and `NewObj` implement describing how they can be constructed from query parameters. The rest should fall out easily from that.

Comment: @Shepmaster, Now that is an answer!, Like an `api`?  that know how to implement !?

Comment: Edit your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806184/how-to-create-a-struct-from-key-value-pairs) to include the necessary details and request that it be reopened rather than posting a duplicate. (Looks like you already did edit the original, so that step is done)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [serde_qs](https://docs.rs/serde_qs) to serialize query strings into structs:

From their docs page:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_qs as qs;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Address {
    city: String,
    postcode: String,
}
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct QueryParams {
    id: u8,
    name: String,
    address: Address,
    phone: u32,
    user_ids: Vec<u8>,
}

let params = QueryParams {
    id: 42,
    name: "Acme".to_string(),
    phone: 12345,
    address: Address {
        city: "Carrot City".to_string(),
        postcode: "12345".to_string(),
    },
    user_ids: vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
};
let rec_params: QueryParams = qs::from_str("\
    name=Acme&id=42&phone=12345&address[postcode]=12345&\
    address[city]=Carrot+City&user_ids[0]=1&user_ids[1]=2&\
    user_ids[2]=3&user_ids[3]=4")
    .unwrap();
assert_eq!(rec_params, params);
```

Comment: I know about `serde_qs`  ,  But I want to learn how to do that in rust, Also I tried to understand `serde_qs`  implementation